# How to delete specific elements of arrays without listing index

Tags: python

```
    Attendance = ['Holly','James','Barry','John','Lewy']



Present = input("Is number Holly present?")

if Present == "N":
    Attendance.pop("Holly")

print(Attendance[0])
```

Is there anyway to delete a specific term from the array by name? This doesn't seem to work? Or can i only delete a specific element of the array by listing its index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can by using *LIST_VARIABLE*.remove('*ELEMENT_TO_BE_REMOVED*')

```
Attendance = ['Holly','James','Barry','John','Lewy']
print(Attendance)
Attendance.remove('Holly')
print(Attendance)
```

The output will be:

```
['Holly', 'James', 'Barry', 'John', 'Lewy']
['James', 'Barry', 'John', 'Lewy']
```